# How to dynamically register a RPC provider?

Tags: javascript, rpc, provider, subscriber, deepstream.io

I'm wondering how can I make dynamic RPC call in [DeepStream](https://deepstreamhub.com/docs/client-js/reqres-client-rpc/)?
For example, when a subscriber call a url http://localhost/myRPCApp/123 , here 123 could be anything. So how can I register a provider method?

Eg:

```
client.rpc.make(<MY-DYNAMIC-URL>, { patientId: 2 }, (error, result) =>{
    console.log(error, result);
})
```

On Provider:

```
client.rpc.provide(<MY-DYNAMIC-URL>, (data, response) => {
    response.send('Hey there!');    
})
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a dynamic URLs like this:

**1) server.js (Used: NodeJS)**

```
const ds = deepstream('<URL>');
const randomURL = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000).toString();
ds.rpc.provide(randomURL, (data, response) => {
  console.log("received request for: ", randomURL, data);
  response.send(`${Date.now()} Hello from random Service: ${randomURL}`);
})
```

**2) client.js (Used: [microjs](https://github.com/zeit/micro))**

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  let fullPath = req.url;
  fullPath = fullPath.split('/')[1];
  const result = await ds.rpc.make(fullPath, {}, (err, result) => {
    console.log("response received: ", err, result);
    res.end(result);
  });
  console.log(`result for ${fullPath} is: ${result}`);
}
```

**now go to**

```
localhost:port/randomURL
```